# Visual Basic 2010 / .NET | Fast POST Request to Web

Tags: .net, vb.net, http, post

I am writing a program that must communicate with a PHP / web based backend through API style calls (POST requests). The code that I have currently is very slow - each request takes 2-3 seconds - is there a faster method or something that I can use to speed up this current method of requests:

```
Function PostData(ByRef Data() As PostData, ByVal URL As String)
    Dim Requester As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(URL)
    Requester.Method = "post"
    'Requester.Proxy = New System.Net.WebProxy("localhost", 1234)
    'Requester.
    Dim ASCIIEncoding As Encoding = New ASCIIEncoding
    Dim DataString As String = "apirequest=true"

    For Each DataItem As PostData In Data
        DataString = DataString & "&" & DataItem.Key & "=" & DataItem.Value
    Next

    DataString = Right(DataString, Len(DataString) - 1)

    Dim RawData() As Byte = ASCIIEncoding.GetBytes(DataString)

    Requester.Method = "POST"
    Requester.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    Requester.ContentLength = RawData.Length
    Requester.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-GB; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"
    Dim NewStream As Stream = Requester.GetRequestStream()

    NewStream.Write(RawData, 0, RawData.Length)
    NewStream.Close()

    Dim ResponseStreamReader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(Requester.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())

    Return ResponseStreamReader.ReadToEnd()
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap the response and the StreamReader in `Using` statements to ensure that they're disposed as soon as you're finished with them.

Also, you should write directly to `GetRequestStream` (using a `StreamWriter`) instead of manually concatenating a string in a loop.

However, the real reason that it's slow is that your internet connection and/or your server-side script is too slow.
Make them faster.

Comment: My internet connection is very fast and the server is also running quickly. Even when testing it with other sites (e.g. Google), it is still very slow.

Answer (score 0):

I remember something about setting the Proxy property to null if you are not using a Proxy.

I still agree with the string concatenation and disposal recommendations and think the code would be a lot easier using WebClient.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim urlphp As String = "" & dominio & "" & carpetanoti & "/demanda_alta.php"
Dim Conexion As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(urlphp), HttpWebRequest)
Conexion.Method = "POST"
Conexion.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
Dim POST_DATA As String = ("&cTitulo=" & "Te necesitamos!!" & "&cMensaje=" & "ALTA DEMANDA TENEMOS DOMICILIOS PARA TI" & "")
Dim byteArray() As Byte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(POST_DATA)
Conexion.ContentLength = byteArray.Length
Dim FLUJO As Stream = Conexion.GetRequestStream()
FLUJO.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
FLUJO.Close()
Dim Response As HttpWebResponse = Conexion.GetResponse()
FLUJO = Response.GetResponseStream()
Dim LEER As New StreamReader(FLUJO)
Dim ServerResponse As String = LEER.ReadToEnd()
''MsgBox("Notificación enviada exitosamente", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
LEER.Close()
FLUJO.Close()
Response.Close()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).